# Generate docx from dotx without Microsoft Interop

Tags: c#

I am using this code to replace 2 words and produce a `*.doc` (destinationFile) file from a `*.dotx` (sourceFile) file .

```
Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat1", "replaced1");
keyValues.Add("xxxxReplacethat2", "replaced2");

File.Copy(sourceFile, destinationFile, true);

using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true))
{
    string docText = null;

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in keyValues)
    {
        Regex regexText = new Regex(item.Key);
        docText = regexText.Replace(docText, item.Value);
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
    {
        sw.Write(docText);
    }
}
```

How I can modify this code to produce a `*.docx` because I need to append some lines to the `*.docx` file in another function.

I don't want to use `Microsoft Interop` because I don't want to install it on server.

Comment: `WordProcessingDocument` is open xml, is docx. I guess it's just the file name that has the wrong extension.

Comment: @dlatikay I tried to change the destination file's extension from `doc` to `docx` but I got a corrupt file

Comment: when you change it from `doc` to `txt`, is it just a plain text file?

Comment: @dlatikay I tried that but the produced `txt` file is unreadable - random chars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did this myself a couple of weeks ago.

Copy the file first then open the copy and change it's document type

```
var template = @"SourceTemplate.dotx";
var destinationFile = @"DestinationFile.docx";

File.Copy(template, destinationFile);
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(destinationFile, true)) {

    // Change the document's type here
    document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    // Do any additional processing here

    document.Close();
}
```

Comment: that works! but when I try to append some lines later in another function I receive an error that ".... because it is being used by another process." I used `document.Close();` as it is in your code but I still get this error

Comment: Not come across that before. I'd be tempted to do as much as you can to the document inside the using before you close it. If it's still an issue then ask another question.